# Expander as ListBoxItem doesn't trigger Selection

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a `ListBox` with `ListBoxItem` using a `DataTemplate` that uses `Expander` as its container. The problem is that `Expander` appears to be eating up `Click` event (`HeaderSite` part of `Expander` to be exact) and I never get the `SelectedItem` if I click on `Expander` (but it works if you click on `ListBoxItem` itself).

Any idea on how to get `Expander` to play nicely with `ListBox`?

Here's a simplified Xaml that will reproduce the problem (no code behind needed):

**Edit** Code updated to bring closer to my actual template but screenshots are still from previous revision (the problem is same - this is just to clarify problem with first answer)

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Selected Item" />
            <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Expander Header="Expandable Stuff 1">
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBoxItem>1.1</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>1.2</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Expander Header="Expandable Stuff 2">
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBoxItem>2.1</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>2.2</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Screenshots are pre-edit**

Clicking on `ListBoxItem` resulting a `SelectedItem`:

[image: Clicking on <code>ListBoxItem</code> resulting a <code>SelectedItem</code>]

Clicking on Expander resulting in **no** `SelectedItem` update (click was on Expander 1 as evident by dashed outline):

[image: Clicking on Expander resulting no <code>SelectedItem</code> update]

Comment: What item in expander should be selected if there are more then one?

Comment: @LPL The expander datacontext in the real app which works fine as long as i click on the tiny margin between expander and listboxitem but obviously i can't get users to do that

Comment: @LPL no problem, anything I can clarify further in that question? Also I'm in WPF room chat if you'd like to talk about it or have any questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without code behind you could do this

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Selector.IsSelected)">
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll check this out too.

Comment: Yup this works too. Two good answers, tough choice! Since I learned from this answer, I'll award you the final answer (and go with this in real app)

Answer (score 7):

Well the following code seems to work with the disadvantage (or maybe advantage) that at each time only Selected item will be expnaded.

Apply the following 2 attributes to your 2 `Expander`s

```
IsHitTestVisible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"
IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"
```

By binding `IsHitTestVisible` as well, it allows the elements contained within the `Expander` to be interacted with.

Resulting in:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Expander Header="Expandable Stuff 1" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}">
                        1
                    </Expander>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
            <Expander Header="Expandable Stuff 2" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}">
                        2
                    </Expander>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```

ANother solution with code behind would be as such:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Expander Header="Expandable Stuff 1" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}">
                <StackPanel IsHitTestVisible="True">
                    <Label Content="1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
            <Expander Header="Expandable Stuff 2" ButtonBase.Click="Expander_Click_1" Tag="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}">
                2                     
            </Expander>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```

And code behind:

```
    private void Expander_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Expander)
        {
            Expander senderExp = (Expander)sender;
            object obj = senderExp.Tag;
            if (obj is ListBoxItem)
            {
                ((ListBoxItem)obj).IsSelected = true;
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: While it solves the immediate problem, it has the side effect that the nothing inside Expander is selectable now (there's a ListBox in there that has other items). I'll edit code to bring it closer to my real code

Comment: Check again i changed my answer and now i think it will fit

Comment: @iltzortz Your original revision is much better (no codebehind!), and most importantly works if you bind `IsHitTestVisible` to `IsSelected` too! Do you mind if I edit with this solution or do you want to do it?

Comment: if you do it go ahead. just do not delete this answer please. Although even i tend to avoid code behind i sometimes go there in order to clean up some of my xaml logic.

Comment: @iltzortz yup binding both attributes does the trick! thanks! Though I'm going with the other answer +1 for the working solution