# WPF Listbox containing Expander controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, expander

I've been playing around with wpf for a few months with mixed success but this one has me stumped. I have a ListBox containing Expanders, something like this:

```
<ListBox>
  <Expander Header="Options">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="Option 1" />
        <CheckBox Content="Option 2" />
        <CheckBox Content="Option 3" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Expander>
  <Expander Header="More Options">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="Option 1" />
        <CheckBox Content="Option 2" />
        <CheckBox Content="Option 3" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Expander>
</ListBox>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to:

1. Prevent the content portion of the Expander from changing colour when it is selected in the ListBox. I want only the Expander's header to have a blue background, not the CheckBoxes
2. Make an Expander the selected item in the ListView when its header is clicked. At the moment you have to click outside of the Expander's header's text to have it become selected in the list view

Comment: For B) see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14522135/620360.

Comment: For A) use a Control with a background color as header or set the backgroundcolor of the ComboBoxes explicitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your first question is simple. Just add this into the `ListBox.Resources`:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
</ListBox.Resources>
```

You are free to change the colours to any that you prefer.

The solution to your second question is *far* from simple. I should like to say that declaring controls inside a `ListBox` is *far* from optimal. A much better solution is to create a data type class, bind a collection of these instances to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property and then to create `DataTemplate`s to define what each item should look like... that is where you should declare your `Expander` controls.

As at StackOverflow, we prefer *one* question to be asked per post, please try what I have just suggested, searching for the relevant terms online if necessary, and then come back with a new question, showing us your new code.

Comment: My apologies for the multiple questions. The xaml you gave above changes both the header and the content control of the Expander. I'm hoping to be able to change the them independently. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: The XAML I provided just removes the default blue selection colour. If you follow my suggestion, then you can add code into your `DataTemplate` that will change the colour of anything that you like... the first step is just to remove the default blue selection rectangle. Once you have got to that stage, add another question and I'll show you how... actually it might be better to search for 'WPF SelectedItem background colour' as this has been answered many times before.