# How to Handle/Workaround Focus-Stealing Custom ListBoxItems that Host Their Own Expanders/Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, telerik, focus

This question is a bit of a best practices / share your experiences / help me discover a workaround for my specific scenario.

The situation is a list box that has a bunch of items that represent shapes in a corresponding diagram; some shapes have sub-shapes (they are containers for grouped shapes).

The desired functionality is to have the list box be able to scroll through all the shapes, and select any via single or multiple selection (and the selected shape(s) are editable via a property grid).

Also, each shape can be dragged and dropped in the list box to change its z-order.

This is currently all working, using telerik controls, but there are some annoying behaviors that I can only fix by creating other annoying behaviors.

I'd like to know if anyone has solved this sort of issue before, or has something to share based on the situation of nested lists in list boxes.

I'll list some of the issues:

1. If the sub shape list (the nested list in the container list box item) is itself a listbox, or if it has editable text boxes, which it needs to have, clicking those text boxes doesn't select the main list box item (the containing shape).
2. Click and drag doesn't happen when clicking those sub shapes if you click on the wrong spot.
3. The list box scrolling gets "broken" (i.e. let's say the expanded nested list has 20 items, and the whole list box can only display 15 visually in the UI, the desired functionality would be that the list box scrolls through the sub items, but it simply skips to the next main item, so you can never see all of the sub items if there are too many).

   1. It's annoying that the focus highlight occurs on the outer list box item after only clicking/editing nested controls on the list box item, but doesn't actually select the item. Only mouse hovering away, selecting something else, and then mouse hovering over and off the highlighted item makes the focus go away again.

I suspect most readers will want to see code, but at this point, I'm testing different configurations for this in a test project, and it's just that, basic itemscontrol inside a listbox item inside a listbox, where the items control has some text boxes on it.

In short, it's "wonky" and I'm wondering if there is a simpler way that WPF or telerik controls provides to handle what I'm trying to do.

I've considered making the entire list box a tree view, but we need multi-selection of these items and that approach would involve redoing a lot of work and data templates.

I suspect I'll need to block out some events and do some other manual event handling, but that seems messy and that there should be some more elegant solution involving focus or triggers, possibly done through XAML.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has found a working setup for this sort of situation, something that allows selecting the main list box item as well as editing controls inside a nested list in it.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/14522135/620360 is useful for you.

Comment: I would bite the bullet and do one of the following:  convert it to a treeview like you said in the post, or actually just flatten all of your items into a single list (perhaps using data templates to add white-splace/emulate a treeview like indentation).   A couple of things I would keep in mind:  1)  code-behind is evil - it will driv eyou insane, and it seems like it probably already is.  Once you get into the business of blocking events and re-routing focus you will never get out.  2)  It's often easier to re-think the UI design than it is to make WPF do things it doesn't want to.

Comment: Thank, @LPL. I solved this by simply using a RadDropDownButton in the far right of the ListBoxItem that has an internal list to display, and displayed that list in the drop down content.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew. I've had some success in blocking out telerik behaviors in order to override them in custom event handlers, and I haven't gone insane yet. I agree with you, though--it's always preferable to use default behavior where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved via changing the requirements (drop down button included on container list box item to display internal list--doesn't interfere with selection and it is easily visible which area can be selected and which will display internal information/lists).